# Evoluent vertical mouse (4-small, wired) manager won't install on MAC OS Mojave

Tags: mac, mouse, macos-mojave

I have just purchased Evoluent Vertical mouse 4 small. On macOS Mojave. I downloaded the mouse manager extension and restarted, however in *System Preferences* the E is there but says `no device attached`.

The software shows in Applications.

I'm using the mouse, but not able to program the buttons with no manager.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to program its buttons with the fantastic [Karabiner Elements](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) which I always install anyway.

Thumb buttons are `button4` and `button6`, wheel is `button5`.

Comment: The current evoluent package won't install at all on Catalina, but I was able to configure Karabiner to fix my buttons easily enough!

Comment: And `button2` being the edge button (the standard 'right click' location), `button3` being the middle button location. And for targets, it has the normal MacOS `fn` keys, so you can assign mission control, for example. Perfect, easy-peasy.

Answer (score 1):

Since High Sierra macOS has enabled Secure Kernel Extensions, which by default limits certain extensions from modifying the operation of your computer without your explicit permission. This permission must be given separate from the actual installation of the driver in question for obvious reasons.

Rather than retype the entire text from the [support article](https://evoluent.com/support/), I'll direct you to read item 6 in the preceding link. After reading that and restarting/reinstalling the driver, the action you need will be on the System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Privacy.

Again, the instructions you need are detailed on the Evoluent support page I linked to.